# Rails / Javascript / jQuery calendar suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-plugins

I'm currently reviewing plugins / code that I could re-use in an upcoming project and would like some suggestions.

I require a library that will allow me to plot events on a calendar. The best one I have come across so far is http://fullcalendar.vinsol.com/ but was wondering if anyone had any suggestions

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars , Take a look, there are many calendar options  in Jquery. But vinsol one is pretty complete in case you want to be able to handle events and other information with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more minimal solution, check out https://github.com/austinthecoder/cal. You control the HTMl, CSS and events yourself. It simply aids in building the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it with ruby on rails, you can use this gem [fullcalendar rails](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails) it provides lots of API functionalities and has lots of features.